# How to display only selected record in listview?

Tags: android

I want to display only one record from the database in listview. (ENTERED PASSWORD RECORD FROM LOGIN).

DATABASE FILE CODE [DatabaseHelper.java]

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Master";   
public static final String ColumnID = "user_id";    
public static final String Column_2 = "f_name";    
public static final String Column_3 = "l_name";  
public static final String Column_4 = "password";
```

SELECT RECORD CODE IN DATABASE FILE

```
public Cursor SelectRecord(String pass) {  

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE password = ?",new String[]{pass});

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
 }
```

JAVA FILE CODE (CODE TO BE EXECUTED)  [Edit.java]

```
final DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

 Cursor c =db.SelectRecord(t1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("text")));

 String[] from={"_id","f_name","l_name","password"};

 int[] to={R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView4};

 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new   SimpleCursorAdapter(Edit.this,R.layout.list_data,c,from,to);

 //ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
 //  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

LOG IN FILE CODE  [LogIn.java]

```
 if (database.checkdata(e1.getText().toString().trim()))
     {
          Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,Edit.class);

          i.putExtra("text",e1.getText().toString());

          startActivity(i);

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           e1.getText().clear();
     }
```

I want to get Only one record in listview which password I entered while login.

**Edit**

Now this code is correct

```
Cursor c =db.SelectRecord(getIntent().getStringExtra("text"));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191863/discussion-on-question-by-nirav-i-want-to-display-only-one-record-from-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only one record based on the password, you need to pass a parameter to `SelectRecord` method.

Assume one of the user password is "pass"

```
Cursor c = db.SelectRecord("pass");
```

**Select record code**

```
  public Cursor SelectRecord(String pass) {    

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
    WHERE password = ? LIMIT 1", new String[]{pass});

    if (cursor != null)
         cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}
```

**Edit**

From our conversation:

> The Error is in the cursor line : Cursor c =
>   db.SelectRecord(t1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("text")));
>
> The error says SelectRecord (Java.lang.String) in DatabaseHelper
>   cannot be applied to (void)

The error is in this line

```
Cursor c =db.SelectRecord(t1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("text")));
```

You need to pass key "text" from Log In to Java File code, so modify this line to

```
Cursor c =db.SelectRecord(getIntent().getStringExtra("text"));
```

No need to have `setText`.

Comment: This answer is very helpful to me.